# Why am I getting invalid syntax on this print statement?

Tags: python-3.x

**Why am i getting a syntax error on line 28? It seems like it should be just a normal line of code that prints the statement, but I keep getting a normal syntax error for it.**

```
print('Welcome to the encryptor program.')
message = input('Enter the message you would like to encrypt.\n')
message = message.lower()
key = input('Enter the key you would like to use.\n')
def encrypt(k, m):
    count = 0
    keyCount = 0
    fullCount = 0
    newM = ''
    while fullCount < len(m):
        if (count) >= len(str(key)):
            keyCount = 0
            num = ord(m[count]) - 97
            if m[count] != ' ':
            add = int((str(k))[keyCount])
            newNum = (num + add) % 26 + 97
            new = chr(newNum)
            newM += new
        else:
            newM += ' '
        count += 1
        fullCount += 1
        keyCount += 1
    print(newM)
encrypt(key, message)
def new_key(k):
    newKey = int('1' + '0' * (((len(str(k))))-1) - key
```

**The line after this**

```
    print('The new key to decrypt the message is', newKey)
new_key(key)
```

Comment: Count the parentheses: `int('1' + '0' * (((len(str(k))))-1) - key`. Can't count them? Stop using so many of them in a single line of code.

Comment: Count the opening `(` in the line @Aran-Fey mentioned. Then count the `)`. The numbers should match. Yours don't.

Comment: now I'm getting a type error for an unsupported operand

Comment: Not me, I get a SyntaxError. If you need help debugging your code, you have to post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok thanks for the help